# How to see which file a user is editing in vi

Tags: linux, vi, privacy, w

If I do a `w`, I can see that a user is editing a certain file in vi.

However there are several files with the same name in different directories.

How do I see which of these files is the one that the user is editing?

Comment: For a related question, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408719/ .

Comment: Shouldn't this question moved to [vi.stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `lsof` selecting the user and searching for the `vim` process as in:

```
sudo lsof -u user -a -c vim | grep swp
```

As @Fox point outs, the classical `vi` creates a temp file on `/var/tmp` so the alternative to see it, should be (not tested).

```
sudo lsof -u user -a -c vi | grep '/var/tmp/'
```

However, as @Fox points out, you won't be able to correlate it with the classical `vi` to the actual file, and then you would need the tools I talk about next on the answer (for classical `vi`, for `vim` it would suffice the `lsof`); *usually* nowadays in Linux you are using `vim` when invoking `vi`.

See [15 Linux lsof Command Examples (Identify Open Files)](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples)

Returning to the `vim` example, we will see then the swap file being used named after `file` is opened as in `.file.swp`

If user `user1` is doing `vi file`:

```
$ sudo lsof -c vi -a -u user1 | grep swp
vi      3615  user1  3u   REG    8,1    12288 265061 /home/user1/.file.swp
```

From `man lsof`

> -a       causes list selection options to be ANDed
>
> -cc   This option selects the listing of files for processes executing the command that begins with the characters of c. Multiple commands
>   may be specified, using multiple -c options. They are joined in a
>   single ORed set before participating in AND option selection.
>
> -u s   This option selects the listing of files for the user whose login names or user ID numbers are in the comma-separated set s

Aside from `lsof`, you can also use as root, `sysdig`, which is a powerful debugging framework:

This will show all files open in the system in real time, listing user,pid and process as soon as they are opened:

```
sudo sysdig -p "%12user.name %6proc.pid %12proc.name %3fd.num %fd.typechar %fd.name" evt.type=open"
```

> sysdig: system-level exploration and troubleshooting tool
>
> Sysdig instruments your physical and virtual machines at the OS level
>   by installing into the Linux kernel and capturing system calls and
>   other OS events. Then, using sysdig's command line interface, you can
>   filter and decode these events in order to extract useful information
>   and statistics.
>
> Sysdig can be used to inspect live systems in real-time, or to
>   generate trace files that can be analyzed at a later stage.

As other useful tool for sysadmins, you can also install `snoopy`, which logs all invocations of processes called to syslog. If the user invokes in the command line `vi file`, you will see it in the system logs.

Beware that after `snoopy` is installed, it will be logging all the process invocations via execve() until you uninstall it (which you might want or not want to be happening all the time).

> snoopy: execve() wrapper and logger
>
> snoopy is merely a shared library that is used as a wrapper to the
>   execve() function provided by libc as to log every call to syslog
>   (authpriv). system administrators may find snoopy useful in tasks such
>   as light/heavy system monitoring, tracking other administrator's
>   actions as well as getting a good 'feel' of what's going on in the
>   system (for example Apache running cgi scripts).

To install `snoopy` and `sysdig`:

```
$sudo apt-get install snoopy sysdig
```

See also the related question: [Understanding what a Linux binary is doing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418354/understanding-what-a-linux-binary-is-doing/418357)

Comment: lsof will also require root if you are trying to see files opened by another user.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for some cases.  You can us `ps` to find the process id of the `vi` instance editing the file:

```
$ w
...
username  pts/2    :0.0             11:42    2:34m  0.28s  0.27s vim foo

$ ps aux | grep 'vim foo'
...
username  55899 .... vim foo
```

Then, as root, look at the open file descriptors associated with that pid:

```
# ls -l /proc/55899/fd
...
lrwx------ 1 username group 64 Feb  8 14:23 6 -> /path/to/.foo.swp
```

Given that, then you might be able to conclude that the file is `/path/to/foo`.

Comment: The `lsof` answers are better choices; that tool provides an abstraction over my answer.

Comment: A test on my system, after `vi file1` then `:e file2`, `w` outputs, among other things, `fox … vi file1`. `ps waux | grep '[v]i file1'` yields PID `14267`. `ls -l /proc/14267/fd` yields `0 -> /dev/pts/24` (same for `1` and `2`) and `3 -> /var/tmp/Ex0000014267`.  This is, of course, neither `file1` nor `file2`

Comment: "This might work for some cases" + "The `lsof answers are better".  Yes, there are cases where my approach won't work.

Comment: I've left almost the same comment on the other answers as well.  The `lsof` command fails in exactly the same way — not to mention that in the `lsof`-based answers, using `grep` will match far more than just the command column, thus generating far too much output

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `lsof`:

```
$ lsof  |grep -i vim
```

Comment: A test on my system, after `vi file1` then `:e file2`, `lsof | grep -i '\bvi\b'` outputs some shared libraries, `/dev/pts/24` a few times, and `/var/tmp/Ex0000014267`, which is of course neither `file1` nor `file2`

Comment: Most editors read the file into a memory buffer or temp file, then close the original file. So you would have to run `lsof` at the moment that the user is reading or writing the file in order to catch it when the file is open.

Answer (score 1):

do you want to see that from inside vi or from the shell ?
-from vim

```
<ESC>:ls list buffers opened
```

I think vi cannot but you can use `ctrl+ww` to swith between files

-from shell

```
lsof | grep -i  vi
```

Comment: you have to filter lsof output of course :) to feet your needs see the answer of Rui F Ribeiro who give you a full example of it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root but do have permissions to read the directories, your best bet is probably to look for the `.swp` files for the file in question (assuming the user hasn't changed vim's default swap location!):

```
$ find . -type f
./1/foo
./0/foo
./2/foo

$ cd 1
$ vi foo
^Z 
[1] 19650

$ cd ..
$ find -type f
./1/foo
./1/.foo.swp
./0/foo
./2/foo
```

Note, however, if you edit `foo` and `.foo` in the same directory, `vim` will need to make different temporary filename extensions:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user grp  12288 Feb  8 14:59 .foo.swo
-rw-------   1 user grp   4096 Feb  8 14:58 .foo.swp
```

So you may wish to look using `find . -user username -name '.*.sw*'`

This feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- what larger problem are you trying to solve?  If you're trying to manage multiple users editing common files, you may wish to move to a source management system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you know what command the user ran, but that you want to know which directory they ran it from (so that if they ran `vi myfile.txt`, you know whether that's `/home/user/myfile.txt`, or `/tmp/myfile.txt`, or something else).

In that case, assuming you're running as root, you can do:

```
readlink /proc/<pid>/cwd
```

where `<pid>` is the process ID of the `vi`/`vim` process you're interested in - that will tell you the current directory of that process, which has a good chance of being the one you want.

Note, however, that:

- The user can change the process's current directory after starting the editor (e.g. using the `:cd` command). You may also wish to check the current directory of the shell process that spawned the editor, though that's not 100% reliable either.
- The user can open other files, and that won't show up in the command line - so they may be editing something else entirely.