# How to see what a user is doing in their ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh, administration, w

I logged into a server as root and did `w`, this let me see that a user was editing a file.

```
someuser  pts/5    10.117.0.53      14:03    3:25   1.20s  1.14s vi somefile.py
```

Then I disconnected, and reconnected as root again later. I did a `w` again but this time it showed something different.

```
someuser  pts/5    10.117.0.53      14:03    5:20   0.20s  0.02s sshd: someuser [priv]
```

I can tell from the other fields that this is the same user, but this time what they're doing is hidden.

Why did it become hidden? How do I see what they're doing?

Comment: It looks as if the user just has a lingering SSH connection running. Why don't you email them and ask?

Comment: I believe that's their ssh connection (a tunnel perhaps?), it may depend on the *nix version, I've seen some poor implementations of `w` , showing disconnected users, non-existing processes etc.


Try a `ps -t pts/5` to see if they have other processes attached to that terminal.

Comment: There was a question here a few weeks ago (I can't find it now) about how `w` decides what command to show. It's heuristic.

Comment: It's https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408719/ .

Answer (score 5):

If a user is using `bash`, you can add to his `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
readonly PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a >(logger -t "commandlog $USER[$PWD] $SSH_CONNECTION")'
```

This will log all the user commands to syslog.

I would configure `syslog`to forward the logs to a locked down central syslog server, so in case of hacking or a rogue sysadmin, they would not be able to tamper with evidence.

Answer (score 3):

If auditd is enabled on the system, you can view the audit logs to see the command activity of users. This is a great resource that sysadmins regularly use when trying to forensically troubleshoot issues that might have been caused by other users actions with regard to the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something simple like peeking at the users history file. This assumes that the user's shell is `bash`.

```
cat /home/someuser/.bash_history
```