# How to run Bash script on startup on Linux?

Tags: bash, startup

I am running Linux 4.9.11-1.0.0 on my iMX7 dual development board. I have a `test.sh` file that I would like to run at startup. It currently only has a bunch of `echo` statements in it (just for testing purposes).

When I flick the switch on the board to turn it on, I see a bunch of initialization stuff come up. I would like the `echo` statements in my `test.sh` file to also be displayed in this initialization sequence on startup. Eventually once this is working, the plan is to do real stuff in place of the simple `echo` statements. I just want to make sure the script is running on startup at this point.

So far I have created the `test.sh` file and I am able to run it manually after the board has booted up. I have added the following to my `/etc/rc.local` file before the exit statement at the end:

```
sh '/home/root/test.sh'
```

I have verified that this `rc.local` file has `#!/bin/sh -e` at the top. I have also done:

```
$ chown root /etc/rc.local
$ chmod 777 /etc/rc.local
```

Once this was all done, I verified that it should be working properly by typing:

```
$ /etc/init.d/rc.local start
```

Everything is working as expected up until this point and I am seeing the `echo` statements when I do that last step. However, when I go and try to reboot the board, I do not see the `echo` statements at all in the printed initialization stuff.

What am I missing? Maybe it is actually running on startup but I just don't see the output for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've done everything such as `chmod +x /etc/rc.local` then your command is running, it's just not getting logged anywhere that you can see it.

#### Example

This is my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/bash
touch /var/lock/subsys/local
echo "hickory stick"
```

Here I've used the modified Bash which logs to syslog which I discussed in this other U&L Q&A titled: [Sending bash history to syslog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457107/sending-bash-history-to-syslog/457108#457108).

When my system boots I see the following message getting logged via Bash:

> /var/log/bash-log/127.0.0.1.log:2018-07-24T22:04:24.609094-04:00 centos7 rc.local: hickory stick

But no where else. To get this to log to syslog/rsyslog you typically can use the `logger` command to do so:

```
$ logger hi
```

You can then see it in your `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` or `journal -xef`. Here I'm using journald:

```
$ journalctl -xef
Jul 24 20:23:04 centos7 bash[1629]: HISTORY: PID=1629 UID=0 USER=root CMD=man logger
Jul 24 20:23:24 centos7 bash[1629]: HISTORY: PID=1629 UID=0 USER=root CMD=logger hi
Jul 24 20:23:24 centos7 vagrant[1811]: hi
```

You should be able to use `logger` to capture output from commands in scripts like so:

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/bash
touch /var/lock/subsys/local
echo "hickory stick" | logger
```

Now when we reboot:

```
$ journalctl -xef
...
Jul 24 20:31:41 centos7 bash[1629]: HISTORY: PID=1629 UID=0 USER=root CMD=journalctl -xe
Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 logger[1286]: hickory stick
Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 sshd[1270]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 sshd[1270]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 24 22:24:00 centos7 systemd[1]: Starting Permit User Sessions...
```

We see our message there via `logger` that we added to `/etc/rc.local`.

#### Extra info

`logger` is a pretty useful and you can have it log to a file instead of via the `-f` switch, you can also control the tag that shows up in the logs with the `-t` switch.

```
$ logger -t "smurfs" hi
$ journalctl -xe | grep smurfs
Jul 24 20:38:24 centos7 smurfs[1764]: hi
```

#### References

- [Shell scripting: Write message to a syslog / log file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-write-to-syslog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in your .bash_profile ? This is a file that gets run on login. So it won't turn on when everyone logs in or technically at startup... but if you are using one user this might be a simple solution for what you need.

Go to your home directory, which if you're root is actually /root not /home/root (at least in the distro's I'm familiar with. Perhaps "echo $HOME" to confirm your home directory.)

Once there, do:

```
ls -la
```

Should see a hidden file called .bash_profile Open it up and take a look. Most have some instructions commented in. You can run your script directly there or just have it invoked with with:

`sh '/home/root/test.sh'`

Comment: Just want to point out that *login* is distinct from *startup*

Comment: @JeffSchaller which is fair, and I do mention in passing. I can edit to be more verbose if this is really bothering you.